# number with special character next to git branch name in terminal (or iterm2)

Tags: git, git-branch, iterm2

I'm a Mac user and use Iterm2 with zsh

When I open my git directory

next to my branch name, there is a **special character** with a **number**

for example (my terminal)

`~/projects/myProject | on git mybranch *1`
`~/projects/myProject | on git mybranch !1`
(As far as I guess, !1 is that a file in my directory is modified.)

I want to know what is the meaning of * and !  and also what number means.

and where can I find information on this special character?

[image]

my prompt :

`${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}${(e)_p9k_t[7]}${_p9k__1-${${:-${_p9k__d::=0}${_p9k__rprompt::=${_p9k__1r-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=8}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+10}}${_p9k__n:=11}${_p9k__v::="✔"}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rstatus+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{070\}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{070\} %b%K{236\}%F{070\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{070\} }${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}${${:-"${${(%):-%j}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=""}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=12}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+14}}${_p9k__n:=15}${_p9k__v::=}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rbackground_jobs+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{037\}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{037\} %b%K{236\}%F{037\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{037\} }${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\#}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=16}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+18}}${_p9k__n:=19}${_p9k__c::=}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}%246Fwith %b%K{236\}%F{180\}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{180\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{180\} %b%K{236\}%F{180\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{180\} }${_p9k__i::=29}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-"${${(%):-%#}:#\%}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=%B%n@%m}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=20}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+22}}${_p9k__n:=23}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rcontext+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}%246Fwith %b%K{236\}%F{178\}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{178\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{178\} %b%K{236\}%F{178\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{178\} }${_p9k__i::=29}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*insert*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=OVERTYPE}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=24}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+26}}${_p9k__n:=27}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{172\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{172\} %b%K{236\}%F{172\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{172\} }${_p9k__i::=36}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#vicmd0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=NORMAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=28}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+30}}${_p9k__n:=31}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{106\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{106\} %b%K{236\}%F{106\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{106\} }${_p9k__i::=36}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#(vicmd1|vivis?|vivli?)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=VISUAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=32}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+34}}${_p9k__n:=35}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{068\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{068\} %b%K{236\}%F{068\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{068\} }${_p9k__i::=36}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=10:17:25}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=36}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(236|236)}:+38}}${_p9k__n:=39}${_p9k__v::=}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rtime+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}%246Fat %b%K{236\}%F{066\}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{066\}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{236\}%F{066\} %b%K{236\}%F{066\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{236\}%F{066\} }${_p9k__i::=40}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}${_p9k__lprompt::=${_p9k__1l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=40}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x236}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+42}}${_p9k__n:=43}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1los_icon+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{255\} ${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{236\}}${_p9k__ss::=%244F│}${_p9k__sss::=%F{236\}}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::="%{d%}${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"\~"}}${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+WebstormProjects}:-${:-"%F{103}"}W${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=15))+}}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+_personal}:-${:-"%F{103}"}_p${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=7))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}react-app-practice${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}%{d%}"}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=68}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x236}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+70}}${_p9k__n:=71}${_p9k__v::=}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1ldir+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__v}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }${_p9k__c}%b%K{236\}%F{031\} ${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{236\}}${_p9k__ss::=%244F│}${_p9k__sss::=%F{236\}}${_p9k__i::=2}${_p9k__bg::=236}}+}}${(e)_p9k__vcs}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}}}}+}${(e)_p9k_t[6]}${${_p9k__h::=81.}+}${${_p9k__d::=$((_p9k__m-_p9k__h))}+}${_p9k__lprompt/\%\{d\%\}*\%\{d\%\}/${_p9k__1ldir-${:-"%B%F{039}"}${(Q)${:-"\~"}}${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+WebstormProjects}:-${:-"%F{103}"}W${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=15))+}}/${${${_p9k__d:#-*}:+_personal}:-${:-"%F{103}"}_p${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}${$((_p9k__d+=7))+}}/${:-"%B%F{039}"}react-app-practice${:-"%b%K{236}%F{031}"}}}${${_p9k__m::=$((_p9k__d+_p9k__h))}+}}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k__clm}+}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for `zsh p9k`—which I tried because you mentioned using `zsh` and your prompt setting is full of `p9k` occurrences—turns up https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k, which in turn describes itself as obsoleted by https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.  This has a very long description; scrolling approximately halfway down leads to the following ([direct link here but this may be fragile over time](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean)):

> #### What do different symbols in Git status mean?
>
> When using Lean, Classic or Rainbow style, Git status may look like this:
>
> ```
> feature:master ⇣42⇡42 ⇠42⇢42 *42 merge ~42 +42 !42 ?42
> ```

followed by a complete table of all possible symbols.  The two you asked about, asterisk `*` and exclamation point `!`, give a count of `git stash` entries and unstaged-change-files respectively.  The table also shows *where* these zsh configuration scripts *got* the information (from running `git stash list` and `git status --ignore-submodules=dirty`, respectively).

(Note that this has nothing to do with iterm2, and is only related to Git in that various Git commands are the source of the items shown.  This question is really about some particular set of scripts for zsh.)

Answer (score 1):

It's your shell prompt (PS1 aka PROMPT).  The first step would be `echo "$PROMPT"` and see what it is set to.

Comment: I did echo "$PROMPT" many code shows up in a line, and It's so hard to read and understand

Comment: You could edit your question to include it.