# Understanding the git symbols in oh my posh

Tags: git

I have the paradox theme on the terminal using oh my posh. But I can't find anywhere what these symbols mean. I tried using the command $ThemeSettings.GitSymbols but I don't get anything (I'm using the v3).
Where should I be looking for?

[image]

Comment: This question isn't really about Git, at least, not exactly. [Here is a related question about zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65500970/1256452). The answer might be similar enough, though I don't use these shells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prompt theming [`JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh`](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh) includes themes based on symbols from [`dahlbyk/posh-git`](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

```
 [{HEAD-name} S +A ~B -C !D | +E ~F -G !H W]
```

With:

> - `≡` = The local branch in at the same commit level as the remote branch (`BranchIdenticalStatus`)
> - `↑<num>` = The local branch is ahead of the remote branch by the specified number of commits; a `git push` is required to update the remote branch (`BranchAheadStatus`)
> - `↓<num>` = The local branch is behind the remote branch by the specified number of commits; a `git pull` is required to update the local branch (`BranchBehindStatus`)
>
> `ABCD` represent the index; | (`DelimStatus`); `EFGH` represent the working directory
>
> - `+` = Added files
> - `~` = Modified files
> - `-` = Removed files
> - `!` = Conflicted files
>
> W represents the overall status of the working directory
>
> - `!` = There are unstaged changes in the working tree (`LocalWorkingStatusSymbol`)
> - `~` = There are uncommitted changes i.e. staged changes in the working tree waiting to be committed (`LocalStagedStatusSymbol`)
> - `None` = There are no unstaged or uncommitted changes to the working tree (`LocalDefaultStatusSymbol`)